# Highcharts Column-chart with php and Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, highcharts

I have a problem with highcharts, beacause I can't load my php data on my highcharts graph that, it will be starting when I click a form (with id=year).
I've done an ajax call and the response is this:

`"{"zone":["NORD-OVEST","NORD-EST","CENTRO","SUD","ISOLE","TOTALE ITALIA"],"elementare":[71,69,59,44,44,59],"medie":[8,5,6,4,3,5],"diploma":[3,3,3,2,2,3],"laurea":[1,0,1,0,1,1]}".`

I have the problem when i have to load this data to highcharts graph, because the ajax call is right but the graph doesn't work..it remains Black with the legend in the top-right.

Here you are my code js:

```
function bottone1() {
    $('#bottone1').click(function(){//bottone1 is my id button form
        var year=$('#year').val();
        if((year!='seleziona')){
            $.ajax({
                url: './php/grafico1.php',
                data: {'year': year},
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    grafo1(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert('non funge');
                }
            });
        };
    });
};

function grafo1(){
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'grafico',
        type: 'column',
        marginRight: 130,
        marginBottom: 25
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Titolo Di Studio',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: '',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [{}]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Percentuale'
        },
        plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.x + ': ' + this.y;
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -10,
        y: 100,
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{}, {}, {}, {}]
}
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "./php/grafico1.php",
    type: 'get',
    data: "",
    success: function(data) {
        options.xAxis.categories = data.zona;
        options.series[0].name = 'Licenza Elementare';
        options.series[0].data = data.elementare;
        options.series[1].name = 'Licenza Media';
        options.series[1].data = data.medie;
        options.series[2].name = 'Diploma';
        options.series[2].data = data.diploma;
        options.series[3].name = 'Laurea';
        options.series[3].data = data.laurea;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }
});
};
```

Here here my graph response:

`{"zone":[],"elementare":[],"medie":[],"diploma":[],"laurea":[]}`

I can't get the data why ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, your question is a bit long. It might be wise to be a bit more specific - you've provided quite a lot of code. You can increase your chances of getting a successful answer by using for example jsfiddle.com, and shorten the amount of code you post a bit.

Comment: You make an ajax call, on success you call function `grafo1` with an argument it doesn't even take, just to make another ajax call and on success create the graph?  Why two ajax calls?  Why not use the data from the first to populate the chart?  Very confusing...

Comment: 1. Does json have a numbers in data? 2. Do you receive any errors? 3. Have you live demo?

Answer (score 0):

I used highcharts in one application with asp.net and json.There are multiple type of Column charts available in Highcharts. which one you are using ?

Comment: xAxis: {
                categories: [{}]
            }, and series: [[{},{},{},{}]

Comment: Can you send me name of Chart Column which one you are using.

Comment: Your JSON String Like - xAxis: { categories: [{}] }, and series: [[{},{},{},{}] this is wrong .JSON String should be like this -        
xAxis: {categories: ['a','b','c']} .in your Json string categories :[{}] is wrong try to create Json string same as given in                                   
Examples on highcharts.com.and in series 
series: [
{name: 'aa',data: [1,2, 3]},
{name: 'bb',data: [4, 5, 6]},
{name: 'cc',data: [4, 2, 1]},
}]
Note data :[int,int,int] --only with out quots

Comment: With static it's ok works fine, with my php that giving json no... and try with: categories: [{}] and the same with series, and [] but i doesn't work...